# Cant transfer dataset from SPARK to HBase table

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase

I have problem transfering my data from dataframe in spark to HBase table  I created.
The problem seems to be that this method can only work with multiple datasets according to examples online, but i have a dataframe with information inside.   Please help!

//HBase table

```
create 'weatherHB', 'STATIONID','OBSERVATIONTS','TEMPERATURE'
```

---

```
   def catalog = s"""{
   "table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"weatherHB"},
   "rowkey":"key",
   "columns":{
   "RecordID":{"cf":"RecordID","col":"key","type":"string"},
   "StationID":{"cf":"STATIONID","col":"stationID","type":"string"},
   "ObservationTSMonth":{"cf":"OBSERVATIONTS","col":"observationTSMonth","type":"string"},
   "ObservationTSDay":{"cf":"OBSERVATIONTS","col":"observationTSDay","type":"string"},
   "ObservationTSHour":{"cf":"OBSERVATIONTS","col":"observationTSHour","type":"string"},
   "Temperature":{"cf":"TEMPERATURE","col":"temp","type":"string"}
   }
   }""".stripMargin

   case class TempHeader(
   recordId: String,
   station: String,
   month: String,
   date: String,
   hour: String,
   temperature: Double)

   import spark.implicits._

   val weatherDF = spark.sparkContext.textFile("1902").
   map(
   rec => List (
   rec.substring(1,26).trim(),
   rec.substring(4,10).trim(),
   rec.substring(19,21).trim(),
   rec.substring(21,23).trim(),
   rec.substring(23,25).trim(),
   rec.substring(87,92).trim()
   ) ).
   map( att => TempHeader( att(0), att(1), att(2), att(3), att(4), (att(5).trim.toDouble)/10)).toDF()

   weatherDF.printSchema()

   weatherDF.createOrReplaceTempView("TEMP")

   val query = spark.sql("""SELECT month, max(temperature), min(temperature), avg(temperature) FROM TEMP GROUP BY month ORDER by month""".stripMargin)
   query.show(10)


   import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase._

   weatherDF.write.options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "6")).format(
   "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save()
```

Comment: what is the exact problem you are getting here ? what do you mean dataframe with information inside ?

Comment: basically im trying to move from spark to HBase table, but imm getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `catalog` has some issues:

- The column family of `RecordID` should be `rowkey`
- The data type of the `temp` column should be `double`

A proper example is given in the [documentation](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc#defined-the-hbase-catalog) of the Spark Hbase connector.

You catalog should look like this (I have not tested it):

```
def catalog = s"""{
   |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"weatherHB"},
   |"rowkey":"key",
   |"columns":{
     |"key":{"cf":"rowkey","col":"key","type":"string"},
     |"stationid":{"cf":"STATIONID","col":"stationID","type":"string"},
     |"month":{"cf":"OBSERVATIONTS","col":"observationTSMonth","type":"string"},
     |"date":{"cf":"OBSERVATIONTS","col":"observationTSDay","type":"string"},
     |"hour":{"cf":"OBSERVATIONTS","col":"observationTSHour","type":"string"},
     |"temperature":{"cf":"TEMPERATURE","col":"temp","type":"double"}
     |}
|}""".stripMargin
```

In addition your `case class` should match this catalog:

```scala
case class TempHeader(
  key: String,
  stationid: String,
  month: String,
  date: String,
  hour: String,
  temperature: Double)
```

Comment: hi @mike, i made the changes to my catalog alr, right now im getting error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "RecordID" does not exist.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fieldIndex$1.apply(StructType.scala:290)" and afew more lines of the java error

Comment: do i have to create a column family of "RecordID" in HBBase? but i doubt that  because i am using RecordID as my rowkey in HBase

Comment: thank you for ur help Mike, i will try it now  .. :)

Comment: Hi @mike , is it possible to transfer only the first 10 entries from SPARK to HBase instead of the whole of dataframe?

Comment: thanks for the advice mike, i m new to this site and didnt know the proper rules and norm in here, and sorry about forgetting to accept the answer.  I didnt know i can do that!